# Want to call RootFrame.GoBack(); multiple times for WindowsPhone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm editing my navigation for my app. It's quite basic at the moment the stack trace of pages would be 3 layers deep:

Main Page > Selection View > Add New Item

From the "Add New Item" page I have a cancel button where I'd like to navigate to the Main Page. I currently have messengers wired up to to App.xaml.cs where inside there I listen to the message and will attempt to navigate back twice with the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= navigationMessage.BackKeyTimes; i++)
{
    if (RootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        RootFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

However no matter how many times I loop through I only navigate to the previous "Selection View" page. Has Microsoft placed some restrictions on how many pages you can go back on?

Comment: `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: Thanks Damith. That would be one work around for the example but then wouldn't the page stack then be 4 levels deep (Main Page > Selection View > Add New Item > Main Page) ?

Comment: Ok, you better read [this](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx)

Comment: @n00b so you need to go back to `MainPage` from `AddNewItem` page if BackKey is pressed, right ?

Answer (score 0):

As the name of the method `RootFrame.GoBack();` already says it should only be used to navigate **one page** back on the navigation stack.

What you could do here is the following:

```
private void Cancel()
{
    // Delete "Selection View" from the navigation stack
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();

    // Navigate back to the MainPage
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?clear=true", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

On the Main Page you can now query the *clear* parameter in the OnNavigatedTo method. If it is **true** call `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();` again to remove the "Add New Item" Page (where you have navigated from) from the stack:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);            
    string clearParam;

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("clear", out clearParam))
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(clearParam))
        {
            // Delete "Add New Item" from the navigation stack
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }
    }
}
```

By removing pages from the navigation stack you cannot navigate back to any other view via Back Button when returning to the MainPage. Is this what you needed?

Please tell me, whether this worked for you.
Good Luck!